# How to render on top of existing shape on canvas using globalcompositeoperation and clipping

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I want to render a blue highlight on top of a shape.

Here's my code:

```js
function renderLight(ctx) {
  const size = 50;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(width / 2 - size / 2, height / 2 - size / 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, size, size);
  ctx.restore();
}

function renderWedge(ctx, rotation) {
  ctx.save();
  ctx.rotate(rotation);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 40);
  ctx.restore();
}

function renderShape(ctx) {
  const x = width / 2,
        y = height / 2;
  
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  renderWedge(ctx, 0);
  renderWedge(ctx, (Math.PI * 2) / 3);
  renderWedge(ctx, ((Math.PI * 2) / 3) * 2);
  ctx.restore();
  
  renderLight(ctx);
}

function view(ctx) {
  clear(ctx);
  renderShape(ctx);
}

function clear(ctx) {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#ccc';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
}

const width = 400,
      height = 400;

function main(element) {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = width;
  canvas.height = height;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  element.append(canvas);
  view(ctx);
}

main(document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
```

I want the blue shape to only be visible where it overlaps the black shape.

Comment: So do you want the entire shape visible when the black has a hover effect or did you want the blue shape to literally show over the edges of each of the black shape

Comment: I want black to show as is, and blue to show on top of black only visible where it intersects black.